# How do I get auto-adjusted font size from TextView?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i'm using

```
TextBox.SetAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(min, max, 1, unit)
```

and this works great. Now i need to get the font size of some text after it's been scaled down. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView.TextSize` property contains the new font size after calculation.